# viewport and texture not the same tint

Tags: uv, 3d-view, texture-painting

I'm trying to get a good preview of the props i'm making. I will not render it, it's for a game. I unwrap my model and setup an image texture, but the viewport colors are not as vivid as the image. Also, I didnt find where I can remove that shadow on the preview ball.

[image]

Comment: Hello, the Material preview won't give you a preview of your render, also maybe show the Shader Editor, you may need to lower down the Specular value for example. You could also share your file, make sure that you've packed the image and upload it here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Viewport Preview

Set the Viewport Shading to *Flat* and *Texture*.
[image: viewport shading]

Then select the texture, that you want to preview, in the shader editor.
[image: select the texture]

#### Rendering

Choose the RAW view transform under Render Settings > Color Management > View Transform.
[image: view transform settings]

Comment: If I select viewport shading, the object is white

Comment: @Richard I omitted crucial information. Please review my edit.

Comment: thanks all good now :) (sorry late answer)